# Trying to fix the error "Record set is not updateable" in access 2007 with a linked SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access-2007

I am experiencing an issue where I try to enter data into a linked table on `Microsoft Access 2007`.

I keep getting the message :

> The record set is not updateable

I have the table linked with a table in `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`.

Originally it was working well until something happened with the primary keys. Every datatype had a primary key, but at some point all PKs were taken away. I know the issue revolves around the primary keys, but I am not sure what it is exactly.

Comment: You're making complex-enough things that it makes sense to move away from access into a better database.

Comment: Office 2007 hasn't been supported for almost 3 years too. Seems like it really time time consider a few upgrades here.

Comment: Maybe your SQL Server tables changed in some way. Try deleting the linked tables and re-link them again. You will be prompted to select unique identifiers if they are not recognized.

Comment: I have no choice in using 2007 access.